# Class library automatically added to the other projects in visual studio 7.5.2 mac os X

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-mac

I, have started working on visual studio on mac os but I, am getting weird errors in project structure. I, have created an empty solution and added the projects as shown in below screen shot.

[image: Errors related to the project structure]

I have created a new Auth.API as ASP.NET core WebApi project and then created two c# library project. When I, create the c# library project it automatically add the project to the Auth.API project as shown in the red mark. However, till now I have not added the project references as well. When I, build the project I get duplicate Auth.API.assembly.information.cs error message.

[image: errors]

I, manually remove it from the project as well but when I, rebuild again same scenario occurs. I, am not able to figure it out where the problem is occur.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have created all these projects into the same folder on disk, which is not supported by default (it is possible to make it work with clever editing of the csproj files but that's likely to hard to maintain).

I suggest moving all the csproj / .cs files of each individual projects into their own folders and then adding them to the solution.

Comment: I, am using visual studio to create all project. I, didn't created on one folder. I just use the visual studio

Comment: What does your folder structure look like on disk? are there multiple csproj files in one directory?

Comment: If the default UX of VS/Mac makes you create multiple csproj files in the same directory, do report it as an issue on http://developercommunity.visualstudio.com

Comment: I too am experiencing this issue, returning to VS after many years using JetBrains IDEs. This is a ridiculous and maddening issue. I want to create a simple application with 
a couple of class libraries I have to add them here and there then manually move them back into the solution. Idiotic MS.